# method_missing doesn't work when used on a polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  post.has_many :comments, :as => :commentable

  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    puts "blah!"
  end
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true

end
```

then in the console:

```
>comment.commentable
=> #<Post id: 1022, title: "something">

>comment.commentable.class
=> Post(id: integer, title: string)

>comment.commentable.blah
NoMethodError: undefined method `blah' for "#<Post:0x10f1e9e10>":Post
from /Users/patrick/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:216:in `method_missing'

>Post.find(comment.commentable).blah
=> "blah"
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: Hmm, works for me in 3.1. My first assumption would be an issue with the proxy class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define `respond_to?` in your class:

```
class Post < AR::Base

  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    return puts "blah" if name.to_s == 'blah'
    super
  end

  def respond_to?(method_name, include_private = false)
    super || method_name.to_s == 'blah'
  end
end
```

The association proxy should then act as you'd expect.